# How does the schedule for a vaccination in multiple injections work?

Tags: vaccination

My doctor advised me to get vaccinated against the Japanese encephalitis before a trip to Cambodia. He recommended three injections in order to get protected for 10 years: a first injection, a second one a month later and a third one six months later.

I know that the basic principle of vaccination is to inject an innocuous version of a virus so that the immune system knows it, and recognizes it and respond to it quickly in case of contact with the real virus.

**Could someone explain how the multiple injections vaccination works?**

As a guideline for answering:

1. Why three injections and not one as for many other vaccinations?
2. Are the three injections in the process the same?
3. How flexible is this schedule? In particular, I had always been confused by the "6 months later" for the third injection. Is it 6 months after the first or the second injection? Does it matter?

Comment: 10 years is a long time compared to 1 year tops suggested by reputable sites. Plus it's 2 doses and not 3.  Look at the relevant pages on [NHS](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Japanese-encephalitis/Pages/Whileyoureaway.aspx) and [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/japaneseencephalitis/vaccine/index.html)

Comment: See also [this journal article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17636750) on clinical tests for length of cover